# Reusing a menu with mvvm and wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, menu

I was wondering what the best approach is for sharing a menu across all wpf windows/views.

My Application doesnt really fit the navigation model, so will probably use a Ribbon control.

I am leaning towards creating a user control for the menu and dropping it on each view, but have also seen Josh Smith's msdn article, where he loads user controls.

Are there any other options or established best practices?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing in a way similar to Josh Smiths; I have however simplified things a bit.

All views are usercontrols, except the MainWindow.
The MainWindow contains a ContentTemplate which is bound to a property holding reference to a single UserControl in the view model.
I then have an ApplicationController responsible for controlling the view and view model lifecycle.
The ViewModel base class used by each view contains a reference to the IApplicationController.
The MainWindowViewModel then makes calls to the ApplicationController to load a new view etc.

Still not 100% on this approach so would welcome any further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would probably try:

- Define an `ISharedMenu` interface
- Create a UserControl which uses the `ISharedMenu` as its DataContext.
- For each ViewModel that you want to use the shared menu, implement the `ISharedMenu` interface.

Comment: Thanks @jberger I like that apporoach and can already think of another situation were it will be of use. The trouble with using it in this case is that i would have to re-implement the navigation logic in all pages and if i use a Ribbon control, that could end up being quite a bit of logic.

Comment: I see your dilemma (about having to re-implement in all pages), but the benefit of the answer I gave is that the logic would only be in one place, instead of every page.  But if it works, go with what you got.